# Set mplayer as default application

Tags: thunderbird, settings, default, mplayer

I just did a fresh install of 12.10 and are now left wondering how to set mplayer as a global default application for video.
I created a mplayer.desktop and added the same categories as totem has, however still no luck selecting it from the detailed Settings.

A similar problem is with thunderbird, which Id like to set as default calendar app. However I can only select gedit, for whatever reasons.

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find a movie file, right click properties, open with…, set default.

Repeat for each movie file format.

TO set it as default, modify your mplayer.desktop like this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Mplayer media player
GenericName=Media player
Comment=Read, capture, broadcast your multimedia streams
Exec=mplayer %U
TryExec=mplayer
Icon=mplayer
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=AudioVideo;Player;
MimeType=video/dv;video/mpeg;video/x-mpeg;video/msvideo;video/quicktime;video/x-anim;video/x-avi;video/x-ms-asf;video/x-ms-wmv;video/x-msvideo;video/x-nsv;video/x-flc;video/x-fli;application/ogg;application/x-ogg;video/x-ogm+ogg;audio/x-vorbis+ogg;application/x-matroska;audio/x-matroska;video/x-matroska;video/webm;audio/webm;audio/x-mp3;audio/x-mpeg;audio/mpeg;audio/x-wav;audio/x-mpegurl;audio/x-scpls;audio/x-m4a;audio/x-ms-asf;audio/x-ms-asx;audio/x-ms-wax;application/vnd.rn-realmedia;audio/x-real-audio;audio/x-pn-realaudio;application/x-flac;audio/x-flac;application/x-shockwave-flash;misc/ultravox;audio/vnd.rn-realaudio;audio/x-pn-aiff;audio/x-pn-au;audio/x-pn-wav;audio/x-pn-windows-acm;image/vnd.rn-realpix;video/vnd.rn-realvideo;audio/x-pn-realaudio-plugin;application/x-extension-mp4;audio/mp4;video/mp4;video/mp4v-es;x-content/video-vcd;x-content/video-svcd;x-content/video-dvd;x-content/audio-cdda;x-content/audio-player;video/x-flv;application/xspf+xml;
X-KDE-Protocols=ftp,http,https,mms,rtmp,rtsp,sftp,smb
```

Log out and in again. You should be able to set it as default.

Source: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1878236

Comment: I don't want set a default player for each format. I'd like to set it as a general default.

Comment: I think the mplayer.desktop I've created was missing something. In general it looked like this one, but differed in such that yours worked. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 3):

go into  `system settings -> details -> default applications`  and set up your default applications as needed, in this case,  `video -> mplayer`

Comment: I have the same problem on 12.04 with thunderbird not showing up as an option for calendar application, any ideas how to include it on the list?

Comment: I guess I didn't make myself clear enough, mplayer is not listed in the detailed default applications. Hence my question. Any other ideas?