# How to set mplayer as the default video application in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS?

Tags: 14.04, nautilus, default-programs, mplayer

I added a new entry under `~/.local/share/applications` as [suggested in another discussion](https://askubuntu.com/a/222318/121652), and it now shows up in the contextual menu:

[image: menu]

However, while in the previous versions of Ubuntu, you could set the defaults by clicking "Other Application...", now you can't:

[image]

If you go through Settings/Details/Default Applications, Mplayer doesn't show up there (even after rebooting):

[image]

So how can I set mplayer (non-GUI) as the default video application in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS?

Here is my `~/.local/share/applications/mp.desktop`:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=MPlayer (FullScreen)
Comment=
Exec=mplayer -fs %u
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Icon=vlc
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=AudioVideo;Player;Recorder;
MimeType=video/dv;video/mpeg;video/x-mpeg;video/msvideo;video/quicktime;video/x-anim;video/x-avi;video/x-ms-asf;video/x-ms-wmv;video/x-msvideo;video/x-nsv;video/x-flc;video/x-fli;video/x-flv;video/vnd.rn-realvideo;video/mp4;video/mp4v-es;video/mp2t;application/ogg;application/x-ogg;video/x-ogm+ogg;audio/x-vorbis+ogg;application/x-matroska;audio/x-matroska;video/x-matroska;video/webm;audio/webm;audio/x-mp3;audio/x-mpeg;audio/mpeg;audio/x-wav;audio/x-mpegurl;audio/x-scpls;audio/x-m4a;audio/x-ms-asf;audio/x-ms-asx;audio/x-ms-wax;application/vnd.rn-realmedia;audio/x-real-audio;audio/x-pn-realaudio;application/x-flac;audio/x-flac;application/x-shockwave-flash;misc/ultravox;audio/vnd.rn-realaudio;audio/x-pn-aiff;audio/x-pn-au;audio/x-pn-wav;audio/x-pn-windows-acm;image/vnd.rn-realpix;audio/x-pn-realaudio-plugin;application/x-extension-mp4;audio/mp4;audio/amr;audio/amr-wb;x-content/video-vcd;x-content/video-svcd;x-content/video-dvd;x-content/audio-cdda;x-content/audio-player;application/xspf+xml;x-scheme-handler/mms;x-scheme-handler/rtmp;x-scheme-handler/rtsp;
Keywords=Player;Capture;DVD;Audio;Video;Server;Broadcast;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click the file you want associated to mplayer I am assuming a Video File then > Select `Properties` > Select `Open With Tab` > and choose `Mplayer`

Comment: Thanks! That was easy (if you know where to look). I wish I could change all "video" types without going through them by hand, but it's not a big deal.